# jquery ui date, setting date from icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a datepicker in an asp.net web app that has today's date set by default. We have an icon that when clicked needs to clear this date (and potentially add 'dd/mm/yyyy' as text back in as some descriptive text on date entry). I've added an icon and created a click event handler on it but I'm having issues setting the date to nothing.

```
$('#dt-clr').click( function(){
    $(this).closest(".datepicker").val('dd/mm/yyyy');
});
```

I've even tried 'destroy' in the event handler above and ('setDate', '') but if that's the best way I mustn't be referencing it correctly.

Any ideas? 
:s

UPDATE:
Eventually realised my icon was on the same DOM level as the datepicker so closest wasn't working (Gaby was onto this too, see comments below). So my code:

```
$(this).siblings(".datepicker").datepicker( 'setDate' , null )
```

...strips out the date and leaves me with a blank date textbox. Just need to figure out how to add the string 'dd/mm/yyyy' in instead of my empty box.

UPDATE 2:
Ok, this works. There's probably a better way, if there is please let me know:

```
$(this).siblings(".datepicker").datepicker( 'setDate' , null );
$(this).siblings(".datepicker").val('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have  you tried

```
$(this).closest(".datepicker").datepicker( 'setDate' , null )
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-setDate

***[Update]*** (*after your comment*)

Have a look at this example i made : http://jsbin.com/obudu/4

Works just fine for all browsers  checked...

I just noticed that you use the `.closest` method of jQuery. Most likely that is what is causing the problem.. The `$(this).closest(..)` must not be returning anything.. `closest` goes up the DOM **tree**, which means that your datepicker object must be a parent of icon..

Give some code about the html structure. Where is the icon in relation to the datepicker..

Comment: Hey Gaby, figured that much out and then saw your update. Doh! Ok, so I figured out that it was an issue with the 'closest' since the icon was a sibling so I've edited my post. I've still got an issue in that I wanted to set the text in the data as 'dd/mm/yyyy' whereas null clears the textbox. I'll keep working at it but I'll keep a closer eye on any updates this time. :

Comment: Sorted it. Did a second update. If anyone has a more elegant solution I'd love to know. There most likely is one! :)

Thanks Gaby!